# Parallel run using RSUBMIT. How to retrieve the detailed data log from remote server

Tags: sas

I am using the SAS parallel execution to run some data step (%macro dataprep) in multiple remote servers.  The SAS log gives the information when the remote tasks commence and complete. But it does not give the detailed log for the data steps (%macro dataprep) that was running in each of the remote servers. Does anybody know how to retrieve the detailed log for the steps that are running in the remote servers?

```
%MACRO BAD_LEGACY(START= , END= );
options fullstimer sascmd ='!sascmd -nonews -nonotes' autosignon;

%DO DATE = &START %TO &END;
%let num=%SYSEVALF((%SUBSTR(&DATE,1,4) -%SUBSTR(&start,1,4))*12 + (%SUBSTR(&DATE,5,2) -  %SUBSTR(&start,5,2))+1 );
%IF %SUBSTR(&DATE,5,2) GE 01 AND %SUBSTR(&DATE,5,2) LE 12 %THEN
%DO;

signon ts&num signonwait=YES;
%syslput def_mth_end = &def_mth_end;
%syslput START= &start;
%syslput end= &end;
%syslput date= &date;

%SYSLPUT _LOCAL_/REMOTE=ts&num;
rsubmit ts&num wait=no connectpersist=no inheritlib=(ACAPS  central arcinp ALSCO ALSleg ALSDTLTB ALSEXTRA ALSSPLIT ALSCOMMT ALSMONTH prjlib pop) sysrputsync=yes;
%INCLUDE '$SASUSER_HOME/parmfile.inc';
LIBNAME CCRD ORACLE USER=&eid_CCRD. PASSWORD =&PWD_CCRD. PATH=F3RDPROD SCHEMA='OPS$F3RDPROD';


%macro dataprep;
DATA ACAPS_CONCATENATION_&date.; SET acaps.ACAPS_ASOF&def_mth_end.; DROP ACCT_NUM PROD_CD_APPRV; RUN;

DATA ACAPS_LEGACY_&date.; SET acaps.ACAPS_LEGACY_DTL; RUN;

%mend dataprep;
%dataprep;
endrsubmit;
%END;
%END;
waitfor _all_ ;
signoff _all_ ; 
%MEND;
```

i have tried the option log = mylog in the rsubmit step but it gave the errors.

Comment: You seem to have left out the RGET statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `proc printto` to save the log to af specific destination.

https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p1hwvc03z4tqlkn1owzhzo8e7ulu.htm